# How to add a new prop to MUI component with TS Augmentation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUI v5 and I'm trying to add a new prop to the `TableRow` componenent. MUI documentation on module augmentation lacks some examples, since it only shows how to add new variants (but not new props).

I tried with

```js
declare module '@mui/material/TableRow' {
  interface TableRowProps {
    clickable?: boolean;
  }
}
```

And in my theme I added the style:

```js
MuiTableRow: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        height: '80px',
      },
      head: {
        height: 'unset',
      },
    },
    variants: [
      {
        props: { clickable: true },
        style: {
          '&:hover': {
            cursor: 'pointer',
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

I don't have any TS error on my theme override, but when using the component, TS throws an error saying the `clickable` prop doesn't exist:

[image: TS error]

How should I correctly add this new prop without wrapping it in a new component?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by augmenting a prop on the TableRow? The MUI component won't do anything with it, and it will just get passed through to the HTML element? If you're wanting a "clickable" TableRow, aren't you wanting to create your own component that handles the prop, and therefore would define your own type definition for the prop?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the new prop to `true` in an interface that might be named `TableRowPropsVariantOverrides` (I'm not sure about the naming, I'm sure you can look into the base code and see if that's correct, usually it's the `ComponentNamePropsVariantOverrides`)

```
declare module '@mui/material/TableRow' {
  interface TableRowPropsVariantOverrides {
    clickable: true;
  }
}
```

Source: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#creating-new-component-variants

Answer (score 0):

This seems a typescript issue to me, but it works properly when creating the project in the JSX project.

If you want to achieve the same in the TSX project, you need to instruct the typescript compiler to avoid type-checking for this particular thing.

Try adding comment `{/* @ts-ignore */}` or `// @ts-ignore` before the line where you're getting the issue.

I've created a dummy project in TSX to demonstrate the issue, you can check this - https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-theme-customisation-xt7yrj

Also raised the issue in Mui regarding this - https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32539

Comment: Always better to properly type the component interface as per @4r5ia comment than disable type checking all together for it.